# Get the vertical scrollBar object of certain column in pyqt's QColumnView class

Tags: pyqt

There is a QColumnView class as shown belown. I use QFileSystemModel as its data model.
[image]

As you can see, there are four columns and three vertical scroll bars and a horizontal scroll bar.
It's easy to get the horizontal scroll bar by using `self.ui.columnView.horizontalScrollBar()`.
But when I use `self.ui.columnView.verticalScrollBar()` to get the vertical scroll bar, it doesn't work properly.
So I would like to know how to get certain column's scroll bar.

When I connect a function to the horizontal scroll bar's valueChanged event by `self.ui.columnView.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.sync)` and I move the horizontal scroll bar, the `self,sync` is executed.
But when I use `self.ui.columnView.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.sync)`, whatever vertical scroll bar I move, the `self.sync` cannot be executed.

Comment: A QColumnView doesn't have a vertical-scollbar. It's just a horizontal container holding a bunch of QListView objects. You need get references to all those objects so you can access their scrollbars: e.g. `columns = columnView.findChildren(QListView)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you very much. I just recovered from the omicron so I'm sorry for not responding in time. I achieved my goal successfully following you approach. Thank you once again.